# No entiendo el resultado de un código de Python

Tags: python, revisión-de-código

Soy un novato total en la programación y estoy haciendo mis primeros pinitos con Python. Y me he encontrado con un código a cuyo resultado no le encuentro explicación. El código es este:

```
x = -12

x -= 1 if x>0 else x+1

print(x)
# -1
```

Según lo entiendo debería imprimirse el resultado -11, pero como se ve me da -1. Lo he comprobado en diferentes programas y plataformas de Python e invariablemente me da -1, cosa que no puedo entender.

Sin embargo, si lo escribo de la siguiente manera

```
x = -12

x = x - 1 if x>0 else x+1

print(x)
# -11
```

sí me da el esperado resultado de -11. Entonces mi preguntas es: ¿no se supone que las expresiones "x -= 1" y "x = x -1" son equivalentes y deberían arrrojar el mismo resultado? ¿Por qué el primer código da el, para mí, inexplicable resultado de -1?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto:

```
x -= 1 if x>0 else x+1
```

Significa que se resta 1 si x es mayor que cero, sino x+1 (en este caso -11), entonces tu expresión queda

```
x -= -11
```

que es igual a decir

```
x = x - (-11)
# x = -12  - (-11) = -1
```

---

Por otro lado

```
x = x - 1 if x>0 else x+1
```

Significa que se establece en x-1 si x es mayor que cero, sino en x+1, por lo que la expresión queda

```
x = x+1
# x = -12 +1 = -11
```

---

La expresión original:

```
x -= 1 if x>0 else x+1
```

Es equivalente a:

```
x = x - (1 if x>0 else x+1)
```

*Notar los paréntesis*, ahí radica la lógica de tu problema

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu precisa y didáctica respuesta, Yussef. Veo efectivamente dónde estaba el problema de mi lectura. ¿Puedo entonces sacar como conclusión que aunque las expresiones "x -= 1" y "x = x -1" son aritméticamente equivalentes pueden dar resultados diferentes cuando se convinan con otros elementos, por ejemplo un if?

Comment: @Pepito es una forma innecesariamente complicada de establecer el número en -1 si es negativo sino restarle 1. Puedes verlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v0LBVkHX0IgrM02hws7AiktBQaFCQddWwZArNac4FcoHKeEqKMrMK9Go0Pz/HwA). En ciertos casos, usar un **shorthand if-else** mejora la legibilidad. Pero en este la empeora.

Comment: Hola Pepito, no, las dos expresiones son aritmeticamente equivalentes y siempre van a dar el mismo resultado. En este caso -11 tal como explica la respuesta. El condicional lo que hace es decidir que operacion aplicas en function del valor de x.